# probability question involving matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $x\neq y \in \{0\cdots, 2^a - 1\} =: S$ for some integer $a \ge 1$, let $b \in \mathbb{Z}, 0\leq b < a$. Choose each entry in a $b\times a$ matrix $A$ to be $0$ or $1$ randomly with equal probability. Let $f :  S\to \{0,1\}, f(c) = (Ak_c)\mod 2$. $k_c$ is the $a\times 1$ matrix whose $i$th entry equals $c_i$, where $c_1\cdots c_a$ is the binary representation of $c$. Here, mod 2 is applied entry-wise. Let $M=2^b.$ Show that $P(f(x) = f(y)) \leq \frac{1}{M}.$

Let $A_i$ denote the ith row of $A$. I think it might be useful to make use of some results regarding independence. In particular, if the following holds, I think the problem would be much easier: $P(\forall 1\leq i\leq b, (A_i k_x)\mod 2 = (A_i k_y)\mod 2) = \prod_{i=1}^b P((A_i k_x)\mod 2 = (A_i k_y)\mod 2).$ Then the problem would amount to simply showing that $P((A_i k_x)\mod 2 = (A_i k_y)\mod 2) \leq \frac{1}2$, but the problem is that $A_i k_x$ is the sum of the entries of $A_i$ corresponding to the nonzero bits of $k_x$, and I'm not sure how to work with that to find the probability (or at least an upper bound for the probability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x\ne y$, there is at least one $i$ such that $x_i\ne y_i$. Let all elements $A_{kj}, j\ne i$ be fixed. We will first work out  probabilities conditional upon these values. For some fixed vector $v$ we have:

$$f(y)-f(x)=(y_i-x_i)\begin{pmatrix}a_{1i} \\a_{2i}\\...\\a_{bi}\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\v_2\\...\\v_b\\\end{pmatrix}$$
Then  $f(y)=f(x)$ may not be possible. However, if it is possible then each component must be zero and therefore the $a_{ji}$ are uniquely determined. Each one has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of being 'correct' and therefore  the conditional probability of $f(y)=f(x)$ is at most $\frac{1}{2^b}.$

But this is true for all possibilities for the elements $A_{kj}, j\ne i$ and so the probability we require is also at most $\frac{1}{2^b}.$

N.B. This is because $$p(X)=\sum p(X\cap Y_i)=\sum p(X|Y_i)p(Y_i).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you elaborate on why each component being zero implies that the conditional probability of $f(y) = f(x)$ is at most $\frac{1}{2^b}$? Also, don't you mean $A_{jk}, k\neq i$? I don't think you're supposed to fix the $i$th row of $A$, but rather the $i$th column of $A$.

Comment: Also could you justify this last statement using formal probability theory: But this is true for all possibilities for the elements $A_{kj}, k\ne i$ and so the probability we require is also at most $\frac{1}{2^b}.$

Comment: You're correct re the typo.

Comment: I've added the formal reason for any events $X$ and $Y_i$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you also formally describe what the events $X$ and $Y_i$ are? From my understanding, $x$ and $y$ are fixed, so $P(x_i\neq y_i)$ makes no sense (there's no randomness). So I don't think you can just define $X$ to be $f(x) = f(y)$ and $Y_i$ to be the event that $x_i \neq y_i$.

Comment: X is the whole event that f(x)=f(y). Each $Y_i$ is a specific case for  $A_{kj}, j\ne i$.